# nodeJS path module can't resolve the directory path

Tags: node.js, node-modules, filepath

I want to create a CLI for bootstrap my project. Everything works find but in order to copy my template files I use [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) where I give the template directory as a argument. So I tried,

```js
import chalk from 'chalk';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';
const access = promisify(fs.access);
...
const templateDir = path.resolve(
    new URL(import.meta.url).pathname,
    '../../templates',
    'project_name'
  );

  try {
    await access(templateDir, fs.constants.R_OK);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('%s Invalid template name', chalk.red.bold('ERROR'));
    process.exit(1);
  }
...
```

I got `ERROR Invalid template name`

Then I tried to figure out the problem,

```js
 //* after getting ERROR Invalid template name
  //* checking file exist or not
  fs.stat(templateDir, function (err, stat) {
    if (err == null) {
      console.log('File exists');
    } else if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      // file does not exist
      console.log("file doesn't exit");
    } else {
      console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
    }
  });
```

```sh
file doesn't exit
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'G:\G:\CLI%20project\create-project\templates\javascript'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: 'G:\\G:\\CLI%20project\\create-project\\templates\\javascript'
}
ERROR Invalid template name
```

I expect the access should be `G:\CLI%20project\create-project\templates\javascript` but it's not giving the that. where was the wrong happened? by the way I use [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) module loader.

Comment: What does `console.log(templateDir)` give you?

Comment: So, have a look at the error : "G:/G:/" will usually never exist.. Check out your scripts

Comment: so when I `console.log(templateDir)` I get `G:\G:\CLI%20project\templates\javascript` isn't it should be `G:\CLI%20project\create-project\templates\javascript`? @MattOestreich

Answer (score 0):

Give your errors a good read.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'G:\G:\CLI%20project\create-project\templates\javascript'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: 'G:\\G:\\CLI%20project\\create-project\\templates\\javascript'
}
```

They're not trying to trick you. They're just telling you/

`G:\\G:\\`

Error messages are there for a reason .

Comment: so when I console.log(templateDir) I get `G:\G:\CLI%20project\templates\javascript` isn't it should be `G:\CLI%20project\create-project\templates\javascript`?

Comment: It probably should be, check out your config files and see why it's adding a static DIR . Looks like it doesnt need that explicit path. (hint) remove the G:\ from your build/whatever scripts
Show us the package.json (related area only)

Comment: I actually follow this [blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=node-cli-howto) and here is the [souce code](https://github.com/dkundel/create-project). I didn't change any configuration @Pogrindis

Comment: Well I didn't write it, so. I can only tell ya the error and where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the answer:

```js
const templateDir = path.resolve(
    new URL(import.meta.url).pathname, // This is where it gives the error
    '../../templates',
    options.template
);
```

Change new URL `(import.meta.url).pathname` to `__filename`. It worked for me.